# How to replace the first two characters of a string, with the first two characters of another string?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm aware that this replacing characters question may have already been posed and I've checked them out, but they still don't answer my question. I'm also new to python, so my understand isn't all that amazing.

```
def stringMix():
    MixA = print (userStringA.replace([0:2],userStringB[0:2]))
    MixB = print (userStringB.replace([0:2],userStringB[0:2]))

userStringA = input("Please enter a string consisting of over two characters ")
userStringB = input("Please enter a second string consisting of over two characters ")

print (userStringA)
print (userStringB)

print (MixA, MixB)
```

That's my code so far, however when I run it, it poses a syntax error highlighting the colon. I simply want to replace the first two characters of userStringA with the first two characters of userStringB, and vice versa.

Comment: its not  clear if you want to replace all occurences of the first two letters , or quite literally only the first two letter ...

Comment: `userStringB[:2]+userStringA[2:]`

Comment: Quite literally, only the first two characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not using method calls properly. ie, you are defining stringMix as a function, but using variables that are out of the scope of the function. I think what you are trying to do is:

```
def stringMix(a,b):
  print (a.replace([0:2]b[0:2]))
  print (b.replace([0:2],a[0:2]))

userStringA = input("Please enter a string consisting of over two characters ")
userStringB = input("Please enter a second string consisting of over two characters ")

print (userStringA)
print (userStringB)

stringMix(userStringA,userStringB)
```

However, as previous answers and comments suggest, `str.replace` is not really the way to do this. you should instead do:

```
def stringMix(a,b):
  print (a[0:2]+b[2:])
  print (b[0:2]+a[2:])
```

to take advantage of string slicing and concatenating

Comment: Ah I understand, you're simply printing the string without the first two characters rather than using the replacing mechanic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, since you only need to print it and dont need to maintain the values. if you do, however, you can have something like `a = b[0:2] + a[2:]`

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf: The reason `str.replace` is wrong is that it will replace all occurrences:  `'fifty-five'.replace('fi', 'xx')` gives `'xxfty-xxve`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do:

```
print userStringB[:2] + userStringA[2:]
```

and

```
print userStringA[:2] + userStringB[2:]
```

Comment: Wow, that actually worked! But how does that work? Please explain, thanks

Comment: This is called slicing in Python. `userStringB[:2]` will return `userStringB`'s first 2 characters and `userStringA[2:]` returns `userStringA`'s all the characters except first 2 and then we concatenate both the returned strings to create result string.

Comment: Please see this link for detailed description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 1):

```
userStringA,userStringB = userStringB[:2] + userStringA[2:],userStringA[:2] + userStringB[2:]
```

I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is a method you call if you want python to *search* for a substring in a string, and then replace it with another string. What you want to do is simply

```
MixA = userStringA[0:2] + userStringB[2:] #from 2 till end
MixB = userStringB[0:2] + userStringA[2:] #from 2 till end
```